# unable to fetch certain table from database corresponding to selected value from selection box using python

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, server

This question could be duplicate but I have checked all the answers of such related questions and I haven't been able to solve it .
I am trying to get the value from a drop down menu and retrieve certain table from database corresponding to this value .
here is the python file

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="mysql",
  database="SugeryClinicDataBase"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST': ##check if there is post data
       Username = request.form['name']
       Password = request.form['id']
       Selection =  request.form['myselectbox']  
       #value= request.form['']
       if Selection==Patient:
           mycursor.execute= "SELECT * FROM Patients JOIN  DOC_PAT on Patients.id = DOC_PAT.P_code Where Patients.id = PassWord" 
           myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
           for x in myresult:
               print(x)                   
       elif Selection==Doctor:
            mycursor.execute= "SELECT * FROM Doctors " 
            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            for x in myresult:
                 print(x)
       else:                 
            return render_template ('doctors.html')        
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Here is Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <form action='' method="POST">
   Username:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="example">
    <br>
   Password :<br>
    <input type="number" name="id" value="10">
    <br>
    Selection : <br>
    <select name="myselectbox" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" value="">
  <br>
     <option value="a">choose</option><br>
     <option value="b">Patient</option><br>
     <option value="c">Doctor</option><br>
     <option value="d">Other</option>

     </select>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

```
I am facing this error :
NameError: global name 'Patient' is not defined
```

Comment: that’s because nowhere in your Python code the variable _Patient_ is never defined, you have to compare strings if that’s what your selection box returns

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help .The error is fixed but there is something wrong when I submit the data it doesn't execute the statement condition and execute else directly .  this is what you mean to do                                                                                    
                        Selection=="patient"